# Starting node gives error saying another node is down

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I am adding a new node and it joined cluster normally until the below error is triggered in log. It says "A node required to move the data consistently is down /10.x.x.3)". But I found that the node was still live and running. Could anyone tell suggest a solution for this?

```
ERROR 10:25:56  Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: A node required to move the data consistently is down (/10.x.x.3).  If you wish to move the data from a potentially inconsistent replica, restart the node with -Dcassandra.consistent.rangemovement=false
        at org.apache.cassandra.dht.RangeStreamer.getAllRangesWithStrictSourcesFor(RangeStreamer.java:244) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.8.689.jar:2.1.8.689]
        at org.apache.cassandra.dht.RangeStreamer.addRanges(RangeStreamer.java:132) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.8.689.jar:2.1.8.689]
        at org.apache.cassandra.dht.BootStrapper.bootstrap(BootStrapper.java:72) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.8.689.jar:2.1.8.689]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.bootstrap(StorageService.java:1143) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.8.689.jar:2.1.8.689]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:933) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.8.689.jar:2.1.8.689]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:729) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.8.689.jar:2.1.8.689]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:611) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.8.689.jar:2.1.8.689]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:377) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.8.689.jar:2.1.8.689]
        at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:329) ~[dse-4.7.3.jar:4.7.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:530) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.8.689.jar:2.1.8.689]
        at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:75) [dse-4.7.3.jar:4.7.3]
```

Thanks

Comment: How did you find that the node was live and running? `nodetool`?

Comment: Yes. I can see the node is up when i executed nodetool status in that node and in other nodes

Comment: I would run nodetool status on the new node, and also the node "supposedly" down.  Most likely there is a communication issue b/w these two nodes.  Obviously, general network debugging may also be required (including checking firewalls).

Comment: Did anyone figure out reason for this?